# How to make a search engine in django with suggestions?

Tags: javascript, python, django, api, search-engine

I want to make a search bar that works with JavaScript. That way, I can add suggestions like Google does when you are looking for something. I already have the search bar and the view to filter the `Patient`s (my model).

Here is the code

```
def search_patient(request):
  """
  Will return all the patients that start with the name that the user searches
  """
  q = request.POST['q']
  results = Patient.objects.filter(names__startswith=q)
  for result in results:
    result.serialize()

  return JsonResponse({'results': results}, status=200)
```

It is a pretty simple function. The problem is that I really think that requesting the new string every time the user types a letter or deletes one would blow up the server, and I don't want that. I really need help here, and I am open to every suggestion.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try elasticsearch? https://django-elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: nop @Abdurrahim. I will check it out. Does this do exactly what I am asking for?

Comment: well, not as intelligent as google but way much better at doing what your sample code is trying to do.I guess this is what you are looking for https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html  you can set a minimum-match to list similar results there,

Comment: Ok, I will check it out; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can put minimum character length on your javascript before the suggestion functionality triggered.

Comment: It would still make a lot of requests, so if it set the min to 5, if I search for my name, Joaquin, I would still make 2 requests instead of, well, idk. Plus, if I would want to search for your name, it wouldn't even suggest anything

Comment: Yah if you use Django database I think that is my only suggestions :) also you can try the Elasticsearch but you need to change some functionality on your saving so that it will also save it on your Elasticsearch.